# Variable Substitution inside a PowerShell Scriptblock run as Administrator

Tags: powershell

I'm writing code in PowerShell. I want to change the port in a configuration file as administrator, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
$port=8888

$ScriptBlock = {
    function bar($port) {
        $config = Get-Content -Path "c:\Users\Me\foo.xml"
        $NewConfig = $Config -replace 'httpPort=[0-9]*\s',"httpPort=$port "
        Set-Content -Path c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\foo.xml -Value $NewConfig -Force
    }
};
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $ScriptBlock,"bar('$port')" -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

I think its having trouble with the second part of the -replace ("httpPort=$port ").

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I can't test currently, but you may need to throw `-Raw` in on `Get-Content`, i.e. `Get-Content -Path "C:\file.txt" -Raw`, otherwise it comes out with the xml file split up into an array, rather than just a single string.

Comment: @colsw: It's fair to assume that the `httpPort=<port-number>` that the OP is looking for is an XML _attribute_ on a _single_ line, so there's no need for `-Raw`. That said, the OP's problem is unrelated to the code in the script block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-Command',
  "$($ScriptBlock -replace '"', '\"'); bar $port"
```

<sup>As an aside:

* The regex you're using to match the port number suggests that it is an *unquoted* attribute value, which, while acceptable in *HTML*, is not well-formed *XML*.

* Don't invoke your function with *method syntax* (`bar($port)`) - PowerShell functions are called like shell commands, without parentheses and with arguments separated by whitespace rather than `,`: `bar $port`</sup>

As for what you tried:

- `Start-Process` invariably interprets the arguments passed to `-ArgumentList` as *strings*, and while a script block conveniently stringifies to its literal string content, you need to escape the embedded `"` chars. as `\"` (sic) in order for the target PowerShell instance to recognize them properly with the (implied in Windows PowerShell) `-Command` option.
- Since `-Command` simply concatenates all subsequent arguments with a space as the separator *before* interpreting the resulting string as a piece of PowerShell source code, it is generally preferable to pass a *single* string, for conceptual clarity.